# How can I measure memory usage in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have such code how can I measure memory usage by loaded module?

Optionally and module load as dependency of this module?

```
import module_one
import module_two

def getModuleMemoryUsage(module):
  # what I should do to read memory usage?
  return 0

def getMemoryUsage():
  a = []
  a.append(getMemoryUsage('module_one'))
  a.append(getMemoryUsage('module_two'))
  return sum(a)
```

What function or module I need use to measure memory usage related to Google App Engine instance to control it - can I use same Python standard functions for it?

Comment: Have you looked at apptrace and why doesn't it provide what you want - https://code.google.com/p/apptrace/wiki/UsingApptrace  as per my previous answer?

Comment: In addition if you don't like the way apptrace presents the information you can use the underlying mechanism to track module memory use by module.

Comment: How can I use underlying mechanism to track module memory? It is not that I do not like `apptrace` - I do not like much more pseudomoderators/content beggars which close question when you suggest solution :) I think to not use stackoverflow in future since can not accept such behavior.

Comment: @TimHoffman Tell me Is Apptrace works with gae/python 2.7?

Comment: Huh? have you bothered to read the docs for apptrace - it has been specifically written for appengine/python.  How about investigating what people suggest to you as solutions, then if they don't work as expected then ask specific questions about how to get what you want.